# Appium test not finding device - "Error executing adbExec; device '' not found

Tags: mobile, appium, adb

The following test was working on my personal setup. I attempted to install my appium testing setup on another machine and am running into the following error. It looks like the test is not detecting the android device.

**Full error:**

```
UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error getting device API level. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command '/Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk' exited with code 1'; Command output: error: device '' not found
```

```
~ adb devices
List of devices attached
RF8RA0778HR device
```

Install latest versions from 1/25/24:

Test Setup:

1. Install Android SDK tools and JAVA JDK

Appium `brew install appium`

Install uiautomator2 driver: `appium driver install uiautomator2`

python version: 3.9.6

Install repo requirements (not sure if this impacts anything): `pip install -r requirements.txt`

requirements.txt:

```
Appium-Python-Client==2.11.1
PySocks==1.7.1
PyYAML==5.3.1
attrs==23.1.0
certifi==2023.7.22
exceptiongroup==1.1.3
h11==0.14.0
idna==3.4
iniconfig==2.0.0
more-itertools==8.4.0
outcome==1.2.0
packaging==20.4
pip==22.3.1
pluggy==0.13.1
py==1.9.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
PySocks==1.7.1
pytest==5.4.3
pytest-html==2.1.1
pytest-metadata==1.10.0
pytest-testrail==2.9.0
PyYAML==5.3.1
requests==2.31.0
selenium==4.11.2
setuptools==65.5.1
six==1.15.0
sniffio==1.3.0
sortedcontainers==2.4.0
tomli==2.0.1
trio==0.22.2
trio-websocket==0.10.3
urllib3==2.0.4
wcwidth==0.2.5
wheel==0.38.4
wsproto==1.2.0
```

Test:

```
from appium import webdriver
from appium.webdriver.common.appiumby import AppiumBy

from utils.page_utils import PageUtils

capabilities = dict(
    platformName="Android",
    automationName="uiautomator2",
    udid="RF8RA0778HR",
    appPackage="com.android.settings",
    appActivity=".Settings",
)

appium_server_url = "http://localhost:4723"

driver = webdriver.Remote(appium_server_url, capabilities)
page_utils = PageUtils(driver)


el = (
    "xpath",
    '//android.widget.TextView[@resource-id="android:id/title" and @text="Software update"]',
)
page_utils.android_scroll(el)
page_utils.click(el)
```

Comment: Android version must be set -> "appium:platformVersion": "put your android ver",

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this was an issue with the UiAutomator2 driver that was resolved in 2.43.1

https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/19713

Updating the driver fixed this issue for me; hope it works for you too!